# rabbitmq consumer monitoring

Tags: rabbitmq, monitoring, spring-rabbit

Few occurrences are reported from Production where RabbitMQ console shown that there is no listener for the Queue.  Logs from application as well as from RabbitMQ server don't have relevant error suggesting the cause.

As prevention, I am exploring what SimpleMessageListenerContainer provides to ensure consumer if successfully created/started/initialized never goes down.

One option is that I create monitoring daemon which keeps checking count of active consumers using SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html#getActiveConsumerCount() and if they are less than expected count, then daemon tries to re-instate them via doStart() or doInitialize() apis .

But before going to explore above option, I feel SimpleMessageListenerContainer would already be ensuring this internally. Is it actually doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The container will automatically restart failed consumers. So something else is the cause of your problem. Look in the application (and rabbitmq server) logs to see if there are any clues as to what happened.